# Cómo ordenar un array siguiendo el mismo patrón de ordenamiento que otro

Tags: array, ruby, ordenamiento

Necesito ordenar un array siguiendo el mismo patrón con el que se ordena el primer array. Sería algo tal que así.

```
x = [2, 5, 3 , 3 , 4, 1 ]
y = ["A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "D"]

x.sort! #Y algún método/bloque/Struc que también ordenase el "y" del mismo modo
#Quedando los arrays tal como siguen.
puts x  # [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
puts y  # ["D", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A"]
```

No sé si existe algún método en la libreria estándar o existe algún modo relativamente fácil de conseguirlo. Muchas gracias de antemano.
Edito: Creía que estaba en la versión inglesa del foro, lo siento, ya está traducido.

Comment: Este es SO en español. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta

Comment: También contarte que en general las preguntas del tipo "Ejercicio de cole/uni" no tienen buena aceptación por acá. Revisa [ask] para que veas como puedes mejorar tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Realmente es para un proyecto personal, y necesito que esa parte del código funcione de esa manera para poder continuar con el mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`.zip`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip) para juntar los arreglos en el orden que vienen:

```
zipped = x.zip(y) # [[2, "A"], [5, "A"], [3, "C"], [3, "B"], [4, "B"], [1, "D"]]
```

luego usar [`sort_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by) para definir la condición de orden. En este caso, el primer valor de los sub arreglos:

```
sorted = zipped.sort_by {|z| z.first} # O zipped.sort_by(&:first) que es lo mismo.
```

Y finalmente extraer los valores ya ordenados que necesites:

```
sorted.map(&:first) # [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
sorted.map(&:last) # ["D", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A"]
```