# ¿Cómo optimizar el ordenamiento de varios arreglos en paralelo?

Tags: ruby

**Tengos tres arreglos:**

```
arr1 = ['d','a','z','f','x','l']
arr2 = [ 5 , 2 , 5 , 2 , 6 , 8]
arr3 = [ 9 , 1 , 4 , 7 , 8 , 3]
```

y necesito que los dos últimos se ordenen de acuerdo el criterio de ordenamiento del primero.

**Esta es la lógica que desarrollé:**

```
arr1.size.times { |x|
 arr1.size.times { |y|
    if arr1[x] < arr1[y]
        arr1[x], arr1[y] = arr1[y], arr1[x]
        arr2[x], arr2[y] = arr2[y], arr2[x]
        arr3[x], arr3[y] = arr3[y], arr3[x]
    end
    }
}
```

**y esta es la salida que quiero pero el proceso no es óptimo:**

```
arr1 = ["a", "d", "f", "l", "x", "z"] 
arr2 = [ 2  , 5  , 2  , 8  , 6  , 5] 
arr3 = [ 1  , 9  , 7  , 3  , 8  , 4]
```

...precisamente este es el punto,

*¿Cómo puedo optimizar el ordenamiento de varios arreglos al mismo tiempo con mucho menos código?.*

**EDICION:**

En base a la sugerencia del amigo lagos probé esto y funciono:

```
a = [6,5,4]
b = [3,2,1]
c = [33,22,11].zip(a, b)
s = c.sort_by {|x| x.first}
```

la salida dió este resultado:

```
s = [[11, 4, 1], [22, 5, 2], [33, 6, 3]]
```

con los métodos first y last obtengo esto:

```
s.map(&:first) # => [11, 22, 33]
s.map(&:last) # => [1, 2, 3]
```

*Lo que no sé es como extraer el arreglo [4,5,6] del arreglo s.*

Comment: Puede que te sirva [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/330539/213)

Comment: Si funciona el ordenamiento, pero falta algo, existe un metodo para extraer el arreglo del medio? solo falta ese detalle

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con extraer el arreglo del medio? ¿estás hablando del código de tu pregunta o algo que implementaste con la respuesta?

Comment: Hice una prueba en base a tu sugerencia, voy a editar la pregunta para explicarme mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map(&:first)` es solo una abreviación de:

```
map {|elem| elem.first }
```

que a su vez es lo mismo que:

```
map {|elem| elem[0] }
```

Si quieres el elemento del medio, debes llamar:

```
map {|elem| elem[1] }
```